How to Automatically Sync ERD Changes with JPA Code?
I am a student studying backend development! In the backend design process, I am looking for a way to automatically apply changes made in the ERD to the JPA-based source code. I realized that during a previous project, mistakes could occur in the manual conversion of ERD to JPA code. Are there any methods or tools available for this?
I tried to use JPA Buddy, but it only supports converting from the actual database schema to entities, not from ERD.

Nothing is free - Since your application will be based on these JPA entities (in theory anyway), model changes will need to be incorporated into the rest of the application code anyway and going to be error prone. In my experience, if a developer makes a mistake mapping the ERD/Database to the JPA entity model, they are even more likely going to make mistakes using it in the business logic. Worse, they might not notice an automatic mapping fundamentally changing things the app relied on. Tools will only get you so far until AI does everything for you
